# mapping polymorphic foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i have to reuse an existing database and have to use Microsoft stuff.
We wanted to create an asp.net MVC application on top of our existing database.
The DB design is as follows (this is a simplification of the problem)

```
Table: Students
  id
  ....

Table: Professors
  id
  ....

Table: Images
  id
  imageble_id
  imagable_type
```

And students and professors can have multiple images, an image belongs to either a professor or a student.
And in the old app you have a person class, which is the parent of both the student and the professor.

My problem is in mapping the polymorphic relation Image to the student and professor.
I have to say that i am new to asp.net mvc and the entity framework. But i dont seem to find a way to get this to work.
such that when you do:

```
Professor a = MyAppDbContext.Professors.find(1)
a.Images.add(new Image())
```

It create a new image in the database where

```
imageble_id = 1
imagable_type = "Professor"
```

I tried defining my own mapping as is suggested by the database first approach, but i cant find how to map this polymorphic foreign key.

ps: i know that the db is not in the 3rd normal form because of this, however the database is not allowed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem... In fact, I don't see any problem here...

Add a constructor to your `Image` class:

```
public Image(int id, string type)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.Type = type;
}
```

Then, your code can something like the following:

```
Professor a = MyAppDbContext.Professors.find(1);
a.Images.add(new Image(1, "Professor"));
MyAppDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And if you are creating a professor:

```
Professor a = new Professor(...);
MyAppDbContext.Professors.Add(a);
MyAppDbContext.SaveChanges();

a.Images.add(new Image(a.Id, "Professor"));
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Update: Getting all profs with their images by a single query against db.

If you declared the navigation properties correctly, all you need is the following line to create an in-memory list of profs with their images in one db query:

```
var ps = MyAppDbContext.Professors.ToList();
```

Now, for example, to get images of a prof., you can use the following and it cause no query against db (as the collection is present in memory):

```
var picsOfProf = ps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1).Images.ToList();
```

Comment: ok, i should most likely be ashamed, but how would you go about efficiently getting all the professors with their images, so that you are not doing a seperate query for every professor, but get it all in one query?

Comment: again, thx :) but when you are doing this on the index page, aren't you still querying n times (where n is the amount of professors) for images?

Comment: @rik.vanmechelen - No... It's not important where you use that code. If you put a `.ToList()` at the end of your L2E query and stroe a result in a var, any queries on that var doesn't cause a db query...